# I'm getting an error while installing React Native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to install React Native on my Windows operating system computer, but I encountered a problem and I cannot fix it. I would be very happy if you help. Thanks

[I am encountering such an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wP6p0.png)

[Everything was normal until here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mrxn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue is with the Android Emulator.
You can try the following solutions:

1. Go to cmd and type `adb kill-server`.
   if the above doesn't work for you try the below solutions.
2. Open **Android Studio**, click on **Tools** and open **Device Manager.**
3. Click on the **Three dots** and use **Cold Boot Now**.
   if the above doesn't work.
4. Simply click on **Wipe Data** of the Device Manager.
   Navigate to your project i.e `cd newproject` and run `npx react-native run-android`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. God bless you I love you so much